# Enable Reorder Control in UITableView as default without being in edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am currently working on a solution where I need to have a `UITableView` by default in reorder mode without having a delete button but could enable the delete button when necessary. I am just curious if this is even achievable in iOS? If so what should be my approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your table view should always be in edit mode.

To make the reorder controls appear you should implement UITableViewDataSource methods

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
```

and

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

If you don't want the delete button to be displayed you can do that by implementing

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle
```

and return .none by default or .delete when you want to have the button displayed.